# Twilio gather Is it possible only support some keys in gather

Tags: twilio, key

I have 4 long messages, when playing the message,
I want to support '#' that end the message, '*' back to choose other message.
So I do like this:

```
function gather() {
      const gatherNode = twiml.gather({ 
         numDigits: 1,
         timeout: 5,
         finishOnKey: ''
      });

      gatherNode.play('longmessage_1.mp3');
}

if(request.body.Digits == '*') { ...
}
else if (request.body.Digits == '#') { ...
}
else {
  gather()
}
```

The question is when user press other key like 1, 2, 3, will cause a break and restart playing message from begining.  So I want to know is it method that ask gather method only support when user click '#' and '*'.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You cannot limit the digits that a user can press with `<Gather>`.

As a workaround, I could suggest a couple of things.

- You could keep the behaviour the same, but as part of your instructions, say "or press any other key to replay the message"
- Or, you could have users press `*` to go back or any other key to end the message.